# Simplest way to use default argument in C

Tags: c

I need to create a function in which there is a default argument:

```
void func ( int a, int b = 1 );
// and
func (1, 2);
func (1);
```

Comment: I don't understand your function , what do you mean?

Comment: @geekInThePink it's like default arguments in C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C doesn't support default arguments, though you can sometimes hack something like them using the preprocessor:

```
void func(int a, int b);
#define TWO_ARGS(A, B, ...)  A, B
#define func(...) func(TWO_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__, 1))

func(1, 2);  /* calls func(1, 2); */
func(1);     /* calls func(1, 1); */
```

Answer (score 5):

It's really simple. There is no default argument in [c](/questions/tagged/c), the code is invalid. You can always use [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) which has default arguments and are very useful. But in [c](/questions/tagged/c) there is no way to achieve that.